# Is it possible to encrypt a config file specified as a configSource from web.config?

Tags: asp.net, iis, encryption, web-config, aspnet-regiis.exe

I have a custom section in my web.config I need to encrypt. This custom config section uses the `configSource` attribute to point at a separate config file (as this file is not to be source controlled) and I'd like for this separate config file to be encrypted. I'm not having any luck using `aspnet_regiis.exe` to encrypt this section.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

My web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="protectedAppSettings" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System,Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />       
    </configSections>       
    <protectedAppSettings configSource="config\EnvironmentConfigurations\ProtectedAppSettings.config" />
  </configuration>
```

My custom configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<protectedAppSettings>  
  <add key="XXX" value="xxx"/>
</protectedAppSettings>
```

I've added aspnet_regiis to my path so I can call it from the root directory of my site. This is the command I'm executing:

```
aspnet_regiis -pef protectedAppSettings ""
```

The output I get from this command tells me that encrypting was successful

I've found [this link](https://forums.asp.net/t/1095869.aspx?How+to+encrypt+a+file+referenced+by+configSource+attribute+) that says that it should *just work* but it doesn't for me..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was because of the type I was using to define my config section. Although there are no docs to prove it, it appears that the `NameValueSectionHandler` type does not encrypt when used for a config source. The solution was to change the type to `System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection` and the encryption works correctly

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. Here is the full reference: <section name="protectedAppSettings" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>

Comment: Also, in case someone wonders, the values are still retrieved as if they were NameValue type: 


var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("protectedAppSettings") as NameValueCollection;

if (section == null)
    throw new Exception("Cannot read section 'protectedAppSettings' from the configuration file.");

string xxx = section["XXX"] as string;

Comment: I also had to specify the strongly-typed assembly, otherwise aspnet_regiis was not able to find the AppSettingsSection class. Similar to @AlekDavis but using the latest .NET version, my full section line is: `<section name="protectedAppSettings" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />`